# Role delay using Rules

Tags: rules

I'm aware of the Role Delay module however it is not working for me. I'm running D7. I read somewhere that it is possible to do the same thing with Rules.

The 3 stages I want users to go through are...

1) Non-authenticated user
2) Authenticated user
3) Trusted authenticated user

I've got the movement from 1) to 2) working fine as it's taken care of by the Logintoboggan module (upon account activation). Moving 2) to 3) is proving trickier as I want it to be time based, after the 1) to 2) event.

All I want users to move from 2) to 3) in 24 hours after they become an authenticated user.

Answer (score 0):

#### Step 1

Create a Rule Component to "Grant a user the Trusted authenticated user permission" (whereas the user is specified as a parameter for this Rules Component).

#### Step 2

Enable the rules scheduler (a sub-module of the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module).

#### Step 3

Adapt the rule you seem to have in place already for that "movement from 1) to 2)" (or create a new rule that catches that as a Rules Event): at the end of this rule, add another Rules Action to schedule the execution of the Rules Component in Step1, after 24 hours.

Optionally you may also want to add some extra Rules Conditions that the user does not have rule "3)" yet (or any other Rules Condition that may fit).

#### Step 4

Next time your cron job runs, the permission "Trusted authenticated user" will get granted.

PS: I'm assuming this question is about D7.

Comment: Hi Pierre, thanks for taking the time to reply. My apologies for leaving out a vital detail which I forgot I had set up. I've updated the question. The move from 1) to 2) is handled by the Logintoboggan module. So I don't have any rules related to role changes, I'm starting from scratch.